# How to change Icon image of QAction when press QToolButton

Tags: c++, qt

1. I want to remove border of QToolButton when mouse hover.
   [image]
2. I want to change icon image of QAction when press QToolButton.
   [image]

i changed stylesheet for QToolButton but it is not working, please help

---

1. I want to remove border of QToolButton when mouse hover.
   I changed stylesheet for QToolButton

> QToolButton:hover{
>           border: none;
>       }
>       QToolButton:pressed{
>           border: none;
>       }

but it display border bottom and button move to left like image

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a “Warm-up”, I started with a `QPushButton`. This class provides the signals `pressed()` and `released()` which can be used to change the icon resp.

`testQPushButtonDownUp.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // build UI
  QIcon qIconBtn("dialog-info.svg");
  QIcon qIconBtnDown("dialog-error.svg");
  QPushButton qBtn(qIconBtn, QString::fromUtf8("Click Me."));
  qBtn.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qBtn, &QPushButton::pressed,
    [&qBtn, &qIconBtnDown]() { qBtn.setIcon(qIconBtnDown); });
  QObject::connect(&qBtn, &QPushButton::released,
    [&qBtn, &qIconBtn]() { qBtn.setIcon(qIconBtn); });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQPushButtonDownUp.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQPushButtonDownUp.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQPushButtonDownUp.pro

$ make && ./testQPushButtonDownUp
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: Snapshot of testQPushButtonDownUp] [image: Snapshot of testQPushButtonDownUp while button pressed]

This was easy. Applying the same to `QAction` is a bit more complicated – `QAction` provides only one signal `triggered()`. I didn't check whether it's emitted for `pressed()` or `released()` – one of the both needed signals is surely missing.

To solve this, I used [`QAction::associatedWidgets()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#associatedWidgets) which

> Returns a list of widgets this action has been added to.

This list is scanned for every occurrence of `QToolButton` which (is derived from `QAbstractButton` as well as `QPushButton` and) provides the same signals.

`testQToolButtonDownUp.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

void connectAction(QAction &qCmd, const QIcon &qIconDown, const QIcon &qIconUp)
{
  QList<QWidget*> pQWidgets = qCmd.associatedWidgets();
  for (QWidget *pQWidget : pQWidgets) {
    QToolButton *pQBtn = dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>(pQWidget);
    if (!pQBtn) continue;
    QObject::connect(pQBtn, &QToolButton::pressed,
      [pQBtn, qIconDown]() { pQBtn->setIcon(qIconDown); });
    QObject::connect(pQBtn, &QToolButton::released,
      [pQBtn, qIconUp]() { pQBtn->setIcon(qIconUp); });
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // build UI
  QToolBar qToolbar;
  QIcon qIconBtn("dialog-info.svg");
  QIcon qIconBtnDown("dialog-error.svg");
  QAction qCmd(qIconBtn, QString::fromUtf8("Click Me."));
  qToolbar.addAction(&qCmd);
  qToolbar.show();
  // install signal handlers
  connectAction(qCmd, qIconBtnDown, qIconBtn);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQToolButtonDownUp.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQToolButtonDownUp.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested again in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQToolButtonDownUp.pro

$ make && ./testQToolButtonDownUp
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: Snapshot of testQToolButtonDownUp] [image: Snapshot of testQToolButtonDownUp while button pressed]

This works but is a bit maintenance-unfriendly – the `connectAction()` function has to be called after the `QAction` has been added to all widgets. (Double-calling it for the same instance of `QAction` might need additional effort to prevent duplicated signal handlers for the same instance of `QToolButton`.)

It would be nice to connect new `QToolButton`s automatically as soon as the associated widgets of such a resp. `QAction` have been changed. I scrolled through the doc. up and down to find something appropriate – without luck. I tried whether the [`QAction::changed()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#changed) signal might provide the required behavior (although the doc. gave less hope) but it didn't work.

Finally, I decided to turn it around – i.e. detecting when a `QAction` is added to a `QToolButton`. However, in my code I add the `QAction` to a `QToolBar` and the resp. `QToolButton` appears automatically. Thus, I made an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters), installed to [`qApp`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp). This event filter will receive any event and, hence, is good to detect any `QAction` added to any `QWidget`. All I've to do additionally, is to filter these events for `QAction`s and `QToolButton`s where the down-up icons are required for.

`testQActionDownUp.cc`:

```
#include <set>
#include <QtWidgets>

class Action: public QAction {
  public:
    class FilterSingleton: public QObject {
      private:
        std::set<Action*> _pActions;
      public:
        FilterSingleton(): QObject()
        {
          qApp->installEventFilter(this);
        }
        ~FilterSingleton() { qApp->removeEventFilter(this); }
        FilterSingleton(const FilterSingleton&) = delete;
        FilterSingleton& operator=(const FilterSingleton&) = delete;

        void addAction(Action *pAction)
        {
          _pActions.insert(pAction);
        }
        bool removeAction(Action *pAction)
        {
          _pActions.erase(pAction);
          return _pActions.empty();
        }

      protected:
        virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *pQObj, QEvent *pQEvent) override;
    };

  private:
    static FilterSingleton *_pFilterSingleton;

  private:
    QIcon _qIcon, _qIconDown;

  public:
    Action(
      const QIcon &qIcon, const QIcon &qIconDown, const QString &text,
      QObject *pQParent = nullptr);  
    ~Action();
    Action(const Action&) = delete;
    Action& operator=(const Action&) = delete;

  private:
    void addToolButton(QToolButton *pQBtn)
    {
      QObject::connect(pQBtn, &QToolButton::pressed,
        [pQBtn, this]() { pQBtn->setIcon(_qIconDown); });
      QObject::connect(pQBtn, &QToolButton::released,
        [pQBtn, this]() { pQBtn->setIcon(_qIcon); });
    }
};

bool Action::FilterSingleton::eventFilter(QObject *pQObj, QEvent *pQEvent)
{
  if (QToolButton *pQBtn = dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>(pQObj)) {
    if (pQEvent->type() == QEvent::ActionAdded) {
      qDebug() << "Action::eventFilter(QEvent::ActionAdded)";
      QAction *pQAction = ((QActionEvent*)pQEvent)->action();
      if (Action *pAction = dynamic_cast<Action*>(pQAction)) {
        pAction->addToolButton(pQBtn);
      }
    }     
  }
  return QObject::eventFilter(pQObj, pQEvent);
}

Action::FilterSingleton *Action::_pFilterSingleton;

Action::Action(
  const QIcon &qIcon, const QIcon &qIconDown, const QString &text,
  QObject *pQParent):
  QAction(qIcon, text, pQParent),
  _qIcon(qIcon), _qIconDown(qIconDown)
{
  if (!_pFilterSingleton) _pFilterSingleton = new FilterSingleton();
  _pFilterSingleton->addAction(this);
}

Action::~Action()
{
  if (_pFilterSingleton->removeAction(this)) {
    delete _pFilterSingleton;
    _pFilterSingleton = nullptr;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // build UI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QToolBar qToolbar;
  QIcon qIconBtn("dialog-info.svg");
  QIcon qIconBtnDown("dialog-error.svg");
  Action qCmd(qIconBtn, qIconBtnDown, QString::fromUtf8("Click Me."));
  qToolbar.addAction(&qCmd);
  qWin.addToolBar(&qToolbar);
  QToolBar qToolbar2;
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qToolbar2);
  qWin.show();
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(5000); // 5000 ms = 5s
  qTimer.start();
  // install signal handlers
  int i = 0;
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&i, &qToolbar2, &qCmd]() {
      if (++i & 1) qToolbar2.addAction(&qCmd);
      else qToolbar2.removeAction(&qCmd);
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

There is a class `Action` (derived from `QAction`) to bundle everything necessary together. The class `Action` uses internally a singleton (of class `Action::FilterSingleton`), so that one event filter is shared between all instances of `Action`.

A `QTimer` is used to add/remove the sample `Action qCmd` periodically to `QToolBar qToolbar2` to test/demostrate whether the auto-management works properly.

`testQActionDownUp.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQActionDownUp.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested again in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQActionDownUp.pro

$ make && ./testQActionDownUp
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: Snapshot of testQActionDownUp] [image: Snapshot of testQActionDownUp while button pressed]

[image: Snapshot of testQActionDownUp while 2nd button added] [image: Snapshot of testQActionDownUp while 2nd button added and pressed]

Comment: @TuyenNH I've little experience with Qt stylesheets. (I prefer a native look and feel which is quite good mimiced by Qt.) However, I found the following in the Qt doc.: [Customizing QToolButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbutton) which refers to [Customizing QPushButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton) which might be helpful. Scrolling up/down, you will find even more examples for buttons. There is also a [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) to find out what's available at all.

Answer (score 1):

For remove  border of QToolButton you can use style sheet like this ( i tested it is work ):

```
QToolButton { border: 0px;}
QToolButton:pressed {background-color: red;}
```

It is remove border and fill background of pressed tool button.

You can not change image of pressed button because usally we add QAction on QToolBar in QtDesignet, and need to change QAction image, but QAction have not signal from "pressed" like in QPushButton.

But if you adding QToolButton to QToolBar manually - you can do that, because QToolButton have signal "pressed" and have property "icon". In some slot connected to "pressed" signal you can change it.