# QMenuBar align QAction to center

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I force set the QMenuBar's width to 40 by the setting minmumsize to 40.
Is there a way to set those Actions to center instead of on the top?
`top-padding` seems not working for me.

[image]

Comment: FYI: [Qt Style Sheets Reference - QMenuBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qmenubar-widget), [Qt Style Sheets Examples - Customizing QMenuBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenubar)

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider to use a toolbar instead of a menu bar. In the toolbar, for each action a `QToolButton` is created. [SO: How to change Icon image of QAction when press QToolButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53208034/7478597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could customize the `QMenuBar` using something like this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyleSheet("QMenuBar { min-width: 80px; min-height: 80px; } ");
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QMenu *menu_a = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&AAA"));
    menu_a->addAction("AAA");
    QMenu *menu_b = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&BBB"));
    menu_b->addAction("BBB");
    QMenu *menu_c = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&CCC"));
    menu_c->addAction("CCC");

    QWidget *central = new QWidget;
    setCentralWidget(central);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

With this code you will get the following menu:

[image]

It's possible to customize the items too:

```
QMenuBar::item { padding-top: 40px; }
```