# QAction icon cannot be clicked

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

After I initialize a QAction with a icon and add it to the toolbar, I found that the most part of this icon in the toolbar cannot be clicked(have no reaction to clicking), only the lower part of the icon can be clicked and triggered. What's wrong with my program?

```
openFolder = new QAction(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/open_label"), tr("&Open folder"), this);
openFolder->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Open);
openFolder->setStatusTip(tr("open a file"));

QMenu *file = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
file->addAction(openFolder);

QToolBar *toolbar = addToolBar(tr("&File"));
toolbar->addAction(openFolder);
connect(openFolder, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::openfile);
```

update：When I set the toolbar to be smaller`toolbar->setIconSize(QSize(20,20));`, I can't even trigger this action through click the icon in the toolbar.

Comment: In the exposed code, I cannot see anything suspicious. Though, if you want that anybody shall try to reproduce your observation then make it a [mcve]. Maybe, your Qt is broken. To get a hint about this, it would be helpful to [edit] in the platform (OS, compiler, Qt version) and how you got your Qt (e.g. binary download, built from sources).

Comment: To give you an example for a [mcve], you may have a look at my answer to [SO: How to change Icon image of QAction when press QToolButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53208034/7478597). (The second code sample `testQToolButtonDownUp.cc` is about `QAction` as well.) Please, note that this is the complete source for a Qt appl. and it doesn't span more than 30 lines (round about). (Something which I very appreciate concerning Qt.) ;-)

Comment: I found that after moving the toolbar to the bottom area, it can work properly. So maybe there is something that virtually cover my icon? my computer is macos, and I'm using QT creator base on qt5.14

Comment: _So maybe there is something that virtually cover my icon?_ This is exactly what you could check with a [mcve]. If you got the minimal complete code  to reproduce the issue you may've actually found the answer by yourself. If not you just got the perfect mcve for your question. I personally have no OS/X at hand but I could check whether this can be reproduced in Windows 10. (to get a hint whether this is OS/X specific or Qt related) Somebody else with OS/X on his/her box might read your question as well...

Comment: Btw. Qt5.14 is quite new. Maybe, there is something broken for the Mac OS/X port.

Comment: I try to make a minimal reproducible example, but I fail to reproduce the problem in a main.cpp file...now I have set the toolbar to the bottom, anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Failing to reproduce it in a [mcve] is an indicator that something else in your application is playing a role you are not (yet) aware of.